# Specyfic xpath doesn't work in pycharm ( python & selenium webdriver)

Tags: selenium

I try to find element, but i have a small technical problem.
I've found element using `//*[@ng-if="device.status === 'ON'"`, it work in `Chrome` ( I can find this element). It doesn't work in `Pycharm` because program doesn't treat it as `XPath`.
In `Pycharm` I try two option 
`x_path = '(//*[@ng-if="device.status === 'ON'"])'`
`x_path = "(//*[@ng-if="device.status === 'ON'"])"`

thanks for help in advance

Comment: It seems that you have quotes issue. Anyway you should provide more details: exception log, `HTML` for target element, your `find_element` statement

Comment: you can also use contains and even 2 contains like                      [contains(@ng-if, 'device.status')][contains(@ng-if, 'ON')] or something like [contains(..) and contains(..)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have quotes issue during finding element, you can escape quotes character using `\` , so you should try as below :-

```
x_path = './/*[@ng-if="device.status === \'ON\'"]'

#now you can find element using x_path
driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path)
```